# Cocoapods error when Initializing react-native app on Mac mini (Apple M1, 2020) running Monterey

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I'm on a Mac mini with Monterey OS trying to init a react-native app.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

gives me:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

when I try

```
cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install
```

I get:

```
  664 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi/ffi.rb
  665 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

zsh: abort      pod install
```

Is anyone else encountering the same problem?

EDIT:

Uninstalled and re-installed Ruby and Cocoapods.

[This was a helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture)

and used:

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: The printout `/Library/Ruby/` reveals the problem. You must not use the System Ruby for anything any more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using that processor does bring some issues with installing pods. Please try `arch -x86_64 pod install` and see what it brings.
Link to some older post:
[React Native ios builds failing suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526954/react-native-ios-builds-failing-suddenly/71026262#71026262)